# How to decompile Java class files which jd-gui decompiler is unable to decompile?

Tags: java, class, decompiler

We accidently got some JAVA source files deleted from the system.

This happened when We checked out a folder from repository directly as an eclipse project and then tried to copy a folder from another eclipse project into this one.Strangely all those folder files have vanished from local system (and obviously they never made it to SVN repository).

Somehow We have obtained .svn-base files for some CLASS files.Now We are trying to decompile class files to obtain the source code back. However some of the class files are giving error "invalid input file" when jd compiler is trying to process them.
Is there any other solution to this ?

Comment: i think if its not so long, then first try a good datarecovery tool

Comment: You say "we". Looks like a small company. You should consider using version control (like Git).

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux - You make it sound like version control is only for small companies.  In fact, the OP should be using version control if he's working as an individual, in a small company, in a large company, in government, in education ... and any other case that I've forgotten.  This has been industry standard best practice for 20+ years.  (I can even remember version control ... of sorts ... on mainframe class machines in the 1970's.)

Comment: Yes, but an individual doesn't need version control for very small projects. As soon as you are working with two, I think it is obliged.

Comment: Thanks @Harmeet. We already tried with almost 5-10 leading data recovery tools from the market. None of them are able to recover the files.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux - An individual can store his precious code on old floppy discs ... but he'd be a fool to do so.  Version control is best practice for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, "jd-gui" is closed source, so you may need to contact the developer to find out what that message means.  (If it was open source, we could just look at the source code to figure out what the likely problem was!)

However, one thing is clear from various questions that Google shows up, and that is that "jd-gui" doesn't understand how to decompile archives (JAR, EAR, etc).  So maybe you just need to un-JAR something to make it work.

The other thing you could try (first) is to see what "javap" makes of the class files that "jd-gui" doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JAD to decompile your files.

www.varaneckas.com/jad/

You may need to unzip your jar files and then run something like the following to decompile them all

```
find <srcdirectory> -name *.class -exec jad -s .java -r -ff -clear -debug -d <dest directory> {} \;
```

I havent tested the above command but hopefully it is almost there...

Comment: Thanks @user846476 but it generates an error saying "Not a class file".

Comment: I have just updated the find method above. There was a mistake in it by the exec command. Can you use jad on just one file? If you can then it is a problem with the find method. If you cannot then something is wrong with how we are using JAD

Comment: but am getting <classname>.class...JavaClassFileParseException: Invalid tag value 0x12 while using **jad** .

Answer (score 0):

I also had the error "invalid input file" with a certain class file. I was using version 0.3.6 of jd-gui. After downloading the newest version of jd-gui (which was 1.6.6 at the moment of writing this) I could decompile the class file which previously failed.

So if someone still has this problem it makes sense to check the version and upgrade if it is an older one. Here is a link to the "Latest-Release"-download page:
http://java-decompiler.github.io/